# How to disable Kaspersky Internet Security Plugins for Firefox

Tags: firefox, plugins, kaspersky

Kaspersky Internet Security automatically installs Plugins/Addons for Firefox. If you try disabling those, they will automatically get re-enabled on the next start of Firefox. Not even Safe mode helps.

I also tried removing the registry keys as described in the [mozillaZine Knowledge Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_Uninstall_Extensions#Uninstalling_manually%7CFirefox) to no avail.

I also saw the solution which [popped up first on Google](http://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?showtopic=309507&view=findpost&p=2319162), suggesting to disable the automatic plugin enabling of Kaspersky and then disabling the plugin in Firefox. However, that was not going to work for me because I had already disabled the full feature (I switched off the whole "Web Anti Virus" feature).

So how can you disable those plugins?

Affected Versions:

- Windows 7/Windows 10
- Kaspersky Internet Security 15

Comment: Can it be disabled in Kaspersky itself?

Comment: What version of Kasypersky and Firefox and Windwos are u using?

Comment: No, it cannot be disabled in Kaspersky

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Open Kaspersky Internet Security (double-click the Kaspersky Icon in the Taskbar)
2. Open "Settings" (bottom link bar)
3. Click tab "Protection"
4. **Enable** "Web-Anti-Virus" (click the switch on the right side)
5. Click the "Web-Anti-Virus" entry to open its settings
6. On the bottom of the settings screen, click "Advanced Settings"
7. On the advanced settings screen, **uncheck** "Automatically activate application plug-ins in all web browsers".
8. Start Firefox
9. Click on the three lines which is your Menu (top right)
10. A small menu opens. Click "Add-ons".
11. Disable all Kaspersky addons you do not want to use by clicking on the dropdown and choosing "disable"
12. Click on one of the "restart now" links which appear next to the plugin's names or just close and restart Firefox to make sure the addons are gone.

Basic solution is the same as provided by GeorgeCT on the [Kaspersky Forums](http://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?s=&showtopic=309507&view=findpost&p=2319162).
I basically only found out you have to re-enable the "Web-Anti-Virus" feature so you can disable the automatic re-enabling of add-ons in Firefox. I cross-posted here to save some poor soul a lot of searching.

Comment: @Stackcraft_noob - An answer being plausible does not make it helpful.

Comment: @Ramhound Did somebody talk to u?

Comment: @Stackcraft_noob thank you for your upvote, but Ramhound is right: if something is plausible, it is not necessarily true

Comment: Generally! Are there any fixed rules for downvoting and upvoting. In my opinion an plausible answer erans an upvote!

Comment: @Stackcraft_noob - Did somebody talk to me about what exactly?  You can issue a vote for any reason you want, but an answer being plausible, does not make it a good answer by itself.  You should not take a vote personally, when I issue a vote, it is based on the quality and technical accuracy of the content.  I personally have very high quality standards, but they can be reached, and I am more then generous my positive votes when those standards are reached.

Comment: @Ramhound Nice explanation! But I didn't read it! ;-)

Comment: @Stackcraft_noob - You took the effort of asking me something, then didn't both to read my response, I don't understand irrational behavior.

Comment: Uh what heated commenting... But thanks for the tip. Too bad Kaspersky is such a CPU hog that we need to disable it in the first place. It works fine for a while and then eats more and more cpu, until you restart the browser, or it reaches 100% of one kernel, making the fan of a laptop go crazy...

Comment: Still working for Kaspersky AntiVirus 18 & Firefox 56